# VLD3.u16 takes a lot longer than VLD3.u8

Tags: caching, assembly, arm, neon

I was benchmarking VLD3.u8 and VLD3.u16 and noticed an interesting result. The input is an array of 1200*1048*3 for VLD3.u8 and 1200*1048*3*2 for VLD3.u16 and I iterated it 1000 times.

> VLD3.u8  :  2.70 sec
>
> VLD3.u16 : 16.68 sec

Sample code

```
pld          [r1, #64]
pld          [r1, #64*2]
pld          [r1, #64*3]
.loop:
   pld          [r1, #64*3]
   vld3.u8      {d0, d1, d2}, [r1]!
   vst3.u8      {d0, d1, d2}, [r0]!
subs        r2, r2, #1
bne         .loop

pop         { r4-r5, pc }
```

Looking at the cycle counter from (http://pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/result.php?lng=us) it takes 4 cycles for each operation (VLD3.u8 and VLD3.u16).

My expectation was that VLD3.u16 would take twice as long to compute since the input for VLD3.u16 is double compared to that of VLD3.u8.

Is this a cache miss issue happening with VLD3.u16, which is causing VLD3.u16 to take a long time to load values into from ARM registers to NEON registers ?

Can someone please help me :) ?

Comment: What machine/SoC are you running on, and how are the buffers allocated? It's certainly possible to provoke some fairly pathological cache-thrashing on some Cortex-A8-based machines if things line up just right - [see here](https://community.arm.com/message/18888#18888).

Comment: Cortex-A8 is also quite defensive on alignment, so if you are able to provide alignment guarantees (e.g. `vld3.8 {q0}, [r0, :128]` guarantees 128-byte alignment of the base pointer) you can often get a speed bump. Later ARM cores are a lot less picky.